# Cant get Android Emulator to start

Tags: android, macos, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I was following a react native tutorial and wanted to get my android emulator going, all I did was create a new virtual device and tried running it, I get an error message stating the following [image]

Looking online, I tried changing the emulator graphics to "software" but that didn't help. Looking at the crash details, I get the following:

Operating system: Mac OS X
10.15.7 19H2

> CPU: amd64
> family 6 model 158 stepping 13
> 16 CPUs
>
> GPU: UNKNOWN
>
> Crash reason:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE Crash address:
> 0x6b0fb8b0 Process uptime: 0 seconds